# Change design of Identity server V3 login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, identityserver3

I've downloaded the following example:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html

How can i change design of login page?

Comment: There is a login.html and a styles.css, you will need them both.

Comment: @Bgl86 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication

Comment: @Bgl86 i cant find it

Answer (score 11):

You edit the login page for IdentityServer using an implementation of `IViewService`.

You can find details of how to do this in the [official documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/customizingViews.html).